# POST entity with relation with the id

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a "Brand" entity with a "Supplier" column.

When I want to POST a brand, with supplier I have to send via the front the value : `"supplier": "/suppliers/1",`

But I would like to be able to only transmit the ID in int if possible

Do you have a lead? I tried to play with my serializer but it doesn't work

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:Brand:collection']]
        ),
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:Brand:item']],
        ),
        new Post(
            denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write:Brand:item']],
        ),
        new Delete(),
    ],
    order: ['name' => 'ASC'],
)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 3.0 you have to do this :

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#plain-identifiers

To help you for your research.
This pattern `/suppliers/1` is called an IRI.
So basically your google search is, "how to use id instead of IRI in api platform" or "how to use plain identifier api platform"

In older version you have `allow_plain_identifiers` inside api_platform configuration.

Now that i have answered. I advise you to stick to IRI. I know it look like painfull to use it at the beginning but it is "how the things should be done" and api platform core team did not put IRI by default for no reason.

From this link : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/relations-iri

> Think about it: the number "1" is not a unique identifier - we might
> have a DragonTreasure with that id and a User. But the IRI is unique.
> And, a URL is also just a heck of a lot more handy than an integer
> anyways.